# Composer Install fails with Checksum on live search

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2-cloud

I have a Cloud project that we have been working on for a few months. This was initially installed via composer and has been running fine for a while.

Recently I had to reinstall the vendor folder and when I ran a composer install I got the following error.
[image: Composer Error]

I tried triggering a deploy to one of the Magento cloud environments and it had no issue but said it had loaded the file from cache.

[image: Composer success from cache]

The composer.json and composer.lock files are the same between that environment and my local. I have also cleared my local composer cache multiple times and I am still getting this error.

Is it possible Magento has changed their release file of one of their modules without changing the version? Is there some way around this error? If Magento in the future clears the composer cache of one of the cloud environments will we start getting this error whenever we try to deploy?

Some technical information

- Magento version: 2.4.3-p1
- PHP version: 7.4.30
- Composer version: 2.2.4
- Live search version: 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Please try following , it may help

```
rm composer.lock
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer clearcache
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install/update
```

Please try this in local first.